# How to remove password strength checker from wordpress profile and reset password page

Tags: wordpress, admin, profile, password-checker

I am using wordpress 4.5.2, and I wants to remove password strength checker from profile page. I just need new password and confirm password field instead of password strength checker

Answer (score 4):

use this code

```
function wc_ninja_remove_password_strength() {
if ( wp_script_is( 'wc-password-strength-meter', 'enqueued' ) ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
  }
} 
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wc_ninja_remove_password_strength', 100 );
```

To do this, add this function in your

```
functions.php file
```

in

```
wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/:
```